# Cannot get Symfony2 Eclipse plugin working

Tags: eclipse, symfony, symfony-2.1

I normally use PHPStorm for development, however I have noticed http://symfony.dubture.com/ plugin for eclipse that looks like it would make symfony2 development much more easy. So I wanted to give it a try.

However I for the life of me cannot get it working.

I have never used eclipse before, but here is the entire process I have gone through

1. Download eclipse (latest version of eclipse classic juno)
2. Install the symfony2 plugin (p2.dubture.com)
3. install eclipse web development plugin
4. Switch to PHP Perspective
5. Create symfony project at existing location
6. Enable javascript support
7. Enable twig support
8. Enable doctrine support
9. PHP Build path is correctly set as according to the FAQ on the site

I let the DLTK finish indexing my project.

I open one of my twig views, and no code assist at all. `{{path('` brings up nothing `{% block` brings up nothing `{% extends` brings up nothing, etc. I do have twig syntax highlighting so I know part of it is there.

Now, I go to one of my controllers
and type in 
`$product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("`

This does bring up code assitance and lists all the available bundles. So I select my bundles, but none of my entities appear, all it says is "No default proposals"
I do get code assist for `$this->get("`

If I rightclick on my project, go to properties, go to builders Doctrine, Symfony, Validation, Script Builder are all present and checked.. Do not see an entry for twig though.

Here is a pastebin of my eclipse log http://pastebin.com/CA76YvKf

I have tried cleaning the projects, repeatedly starting my entire process over and over again, even on different machines and always this exact same results

I know a lot of people are using it, so I must just be doing something wrong.. If anyone here has any suggestions that would be great.

Comment: Didn't work for me either, it throws random errors, so now I'm trying netbeans again. If only I could make the 'scanning projects' thing stop... Otherwise I will have to go back to gedit.

Comment: Worked for me on Indigo right out of the box. Have you tried installing it into the preconfigured [Zend PDT](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt/downloads) release.

Comment: @james_t I tried fresh indigo right outof box, same issue. I tried the Zend PDT and I can't seem to install the symfony plugin without errors from "install new software", and when I try to install it from the zend extension manager, it forces me to upgrade to zend studio.. Tried upgrading it just to see, still didn't work. I have tried both my project as well as the skeleton symfony project same issue. I just don't get what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Have you tried project > configure > add php support, and making sure everything relevant is ticked in the build paths for the project?

Comment: The add php support is greyed out.. I assume it already has it.  And build paths look fine

Answer (score 1):

The way I do:

- download eclipse (juno)
- install pdt for eclipse (http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation_3.1.x) // as you can see: 'PHP Development Tools (PDT) Runtime Feature' under 'PHP Development Tools'
- create php project
- contextual menu on the project > configure > add php support
- install the symfony2 plugin (p2.dubture.com)
- contextual menu on the project > configure > convert to symfony project

hope this helps.